# User file very big

Tags: macos

my users file in macbook air 11" is 30 GB. How can I free up some of this storage space? I can't upgrade to Yosemite until I have more free storage.

Comment: What is the "users file"?

Answer (score 1):

Run a utility like the excellent (and free) [Disk Inventory X](http://www.derlien.com), this will show you which files are consuming the most space and you will then be able to decide what needs to go to make space. If you find it useful consider making a small donation - it's been around for a few years and proven invaluable at times ;-)

You should also think about upgrading your drive size. If you don't have enough room to install Yosemite you probably don't have enough space for the system to "breathe" properly - there should always be a few GB free for temporary system files (swap files etc.)...

Answer (score 1):

1. Back up your Mac (start a Time Machine backup and continue to investigate)
2. Open finder and select the Macintosh HD and press Command 2 and then Command J (this selects list view and then make sure "Calculate All Sizes" is checked for that finder window. Optionally check use as defaults if you want all finder windows to show you sizes of files and folders.)
3. Click on Size and then wait for the system to add up all the sizes in each folder.

Don't delete things yet, but use the triangles next to folders to dive down and see what areas large files exist (10 GB or larger).

Once the backup finishes you can make decisions on what to delete or move to another drive temporarily. Post a new thread if you need help running Disk Utility or if the files are in trash, etc... Also, be careful to not delete system files if you don't have a plan to reinstall your OS.